# Using SQL in Azure Databricks, want to return date for 'N' business days before given date

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

Lets take eg of '2023-07-25'. I want to get the date for 15 business days ago (excluding weekends and holidays). I do have a table called 'holidays' which contains the list of all holidays which I can join with.

What is the best approach to do it in Azure Databricks using %sql ?

Comment: I have figured that i can use the dayofweek() function to get the value and i can check for weekend. So essentially, I have a way to check for holidays and weekend, but I cant seem to figure out a way to iterate it.

I am new to using databricks and don't really know if scalar functions work.

Comment: Are you sure databricks uses SQL Server T-SQL? I didn't think it did, in which case you might remove that tag.

Comment: This could be easier in `%python`. Is it _always_ based off todays date? Because you could have a daily process the precalcs a calendar table (a table with a list of every date) and assigns "number of business days prior" to each record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command for getting working days.

```
%sql
select
input_date,
(DATEDIFF(input_date, DATE_SUB(input_date, 15))) as total_cnt,
(select  count(*)
from
(SELECT  date_format(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(input_date, 15), seq),'E') not  in ('Sat','Sun') as weekbools
FROM (SELECT  EXPLODE(sequence(0, DATEDIFF(input_date, DATE_SUB(input_date, 15)))) AS seq)
WHERE  DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(input_date, 15), seq) != input_date)
where weekbools='true') as weekdayscnt,
(SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT holiday_date)
FROM holidays
WHERE holiday_date BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(input_date, 15) AND input_date) as holiday_cnt,
(weekdayscnt-holiday_cnt) as working_days
from
input_date_table;
```

Output:

[image]

Or you can get dates for last 15 days not having `Sat,San` and do join operation on `holiday` table.

Below is the command.

```
%sql
SELECT
(SELECT  count(*)
from holidays
RIGHT  JOIN
(SELECT
DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(input_date, 15), seq) as dates
FROM (SELECT  EXPLODE(sequence(0, DATEDIFF(input_date, DATE_SUB(input_date, 15)))) AS seq)
WHERE  DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(input_date, 15), seq) != input_date and  date_format(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(input_date, 15), seq),'E') not  in ('Sat','Sun')) as date_tbl
ON
holidays.holiday_date=date_tbl.dates
WHERE holidays.holiday_date IS NULL) as working_days
FROM
input_date_table;
```

Output:

[image]